# Building FAQ lists with Keystone Lists

Tags: keystonejs

Here is the pseudo-code of what I want:

```
FAQ = {
   name: 'Foobar FAQ',
   items:[
     //question/answer pairs here
   ]
}
```

How can I accomplish this in Keystone?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var FAQ = new keystone.List('FAQ',{
    track: true
});

FAQ.add({
    name: {type: String}
    items: {} // ???
});

FAQ.register();
```

I'm unsure how to accomplish this. I'm brand new to React, Keystonejs and Mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done through a Relationship field type.

```
    items: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Pair', many: true }
```

where Pair is the name of your Question/Answer pair list object.

For more info, see: http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationships